# bar graph with percent and in graph labels using ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I am new to R and trying to create a bar graph of with percentages for different groups of categorical variables (degree). Here is the code I am working with so far:

```
 graph_data <- gss %>% 
            group_by(degree, owngun) %>%
            summarise(total = n()) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            mutate(percent = total/57061)     

       ggplot(graph_data, aes(x=degree, fill=owngun, y=percent) +
            geom_bar(stat="identity") +
            geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

The first part works and I am able to create a new variable with the percent of gunowners. However, when I run the second part to graph the variables, I get the following error messages:

```
 > ggplot(aes(x=degree, fill=owngun, y=percent) +
        +   geom_bar(stat="identity")
        + ggplot(graph_data, aes(x=degree, fill=owngun, y=percent) +
        Error: unexpected symbol in:
       "  geom_bar(stat="identity")
        ggplot"
       >   geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        +   geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
       Error in position_stack(vjust = 0.5) : unused argument (vjust = 0.5)
```

Comment: there's a closing bracket missing in `ggplot(aes())`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong in the second part. I've done my best to correct it, but depending on how your dataset is defined, this may or may not completely solve the problem

`ggplot(graph_data, aes(x=degree, y=percent, fill=owngun)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`

To expand on what was wrong, you defined `ggplot()` twice. You should only ever need to do so once. `ggplot()` defines the "global" parameters for the chart. You also repeated `geom_bar()` twice, I don't know if that would throw an error, but you certainly only need one instance. Your parentheses were wrong around both `ggplot()` lines, you were missing a second ")" both times, which in and of itself would cause the graph not to work.

Comment: Thank you, using your suggestions, I made some adjustments and was able to get the code to work:

Comment: @Christina According to your comment, the answer of HenryRice helped to solve your issue. Then you should consider [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I made some adjustments using your suggestions and was able to get the code to work using the following:

```
ggplot(graph_data, aes(x=degree, y=percent, fill=owngun, label=percent)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(size = 3, position="stack")
```

The only issue remaining is that the text is positioned in places that make it hard to read. I will work on that.

Comment: Besides the fact that the [answer of Henry Rice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42357529/3817004) has solved your issue (according to your own comment) it is pretty useless for other SO users that you post your own answer as you haven't provided any data to reproduce your problem and the final solution in your answer.